# Double not being passed down in from method to method

Tags: java

I designed a small program where I have three exam grades and I use the Grades class to compute the average of the three. Also, I prompt for the exam number (1,2, or 3) and it should return it. However, I keep getting 0.0 as the output for both the average exam score and chosen exam score.

```
package GradesClass;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradesDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Grades school = new Grades(90.9,87.9,99.9);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter desired test number: ");
        int testnumber = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println(school);
        System.out.println("Exam score: " + school.getGrades(testnumber));
    }
}

package GradesClass;

public class Grades {   
    private double num1, num2, num3;
    private int testnumber;
    private double average;

    public Grades(double num1, double num2, double num3) {
        num1 = 0;
        num2 = 0;
        num3 = 0;
    }
    public void setGrades(double scorenumber, int testnumber) {
        if (testnumber == 1) {
            num1 = scorenumber;
        } else if (testnumber == 2) {
            num2 = scorenumber;
        } else {
            num3 = scorenumber;
        }
    }
    public double getGrades(int testnumber) {
        if (testnumber == 1) {
            return(num1);
        } else if (testnumber == 2) {
            return(num2);
        } else {
            return(num3);
        }
    }
    public double average(double num1, double num2, double num3) {
        average = ((num1+num2+num3)/3.0);
        return(average);
    }
    public String toString() {
        return("Average: " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you add some more print statements to your classes to see what values come in and go out. That is called debugging, and an essential part of learning programming. Programming is not just writing code. It is the ability to understand what code is doing. Don't delegate that work to other people.

Comment: But most likely the issue is that, our assign all 0 to your values in that constructor. Ignoring all the parameters passed to it! 0 + 0 + 0 doesn't add up much.

Answer (score 4):

In your constructor for Grades you are setting the member variables to zero instead of the values supplied in the parameters. Change the constructor to

```
public Grades(double num1, double num2, double num3) {
    this.num1 = num1;
    this.num2 = num2;
    this.num3 = num3;
}
```

Comment: What does this. mean?

Comment: It means the current instance of the class, the object that gets created by the constructor. You can always reference the object from inside the methods of the class to access members, mostly you don't need to and can just write the name of the member but in this example the members and the parameters has the same name so you must use this.num1 for instance to separate it from the parameter num1